# Hibernate Reimb is not mapped

Tags: java, hibernate

I've had this error before, but it was because I was pointing to the table name (user) instead of the class name (Users). The reimbursement table exists on my db with my Users table and I can pull information from it using normal SQL commands through my DBeaver scripts. This time I'm at a complete loss for why I'm being told it's not mapped.

Exception: Reimb is not mapped

[Select reimb_id, firstname, lastname, amount, type_id, description, submit_date, status_id, resolve_date From Reimb Left join Users Order by status_id]

My Reimb class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "reimbursement", schema = "ers")
public class Reimb {
```

The HQL statement:

```
String hql = "Select reimb_id, firstname, lastname, amount, type_id, " +
                        "description, submit_date, status_id, resolve_date " +
                        "From Reimb " +
                        "Left join Users " +
                        "Order by status_id";

Query q = session.createQuery(hql).setMaxResults(20);
```

I've tried doing @Entity(name = "Reimb") as I saw in a previous solution, but that didn't help either.

Comment: How did you tell Hibernate about your mapped classes existence? Are you sure they are recognized at all?

Comment: I used annotations instead of a configuration file. The Users.java class is recognized and the parts of the website I'm putting together that utilize the Users.java class inside of HQL statements work fine. The Reimb.java is giving me issues though (as explained above).

Answer (score 2):

I forgot to add

```
    configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Reimb.class);
```

to my Hibernate Configuration.